# Solve an equation using a python numerical solver in numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, equation, solver

I have an equation, as follows:

`R - ((1.0 - np.exp(-tau))/(1.0 - np.exp(-a*tau))) = 0`.

I want to solve for `tau` in this equation using a numerical solver available within numpy. What is the best way to go about this?

The values for `R` and `a` in this equation vary for different implementations of this formula, but are fixed at particular values when it is to be solved for tau.

Comment: I am pretty sure, that this equation has an analytical solution in C

Comment: I would not think so unless you can pinpoint it. I tried using Newton's method using Python, but it seems to depend on the way the equation is written.

Comment: try wolfram's alpha solver, when you put particular R and a it gives you nice, clean solutions in C.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In conventional mathematical notation, your equation is

[image: $$ R = \frac{1 - e^{-\tau}}{1 - e^{-a\cdot\tau}}$$]

The SciPy [`fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) function searches for a point at which a given expression equals zero (a "zero" or "root" of the expression).   You'll need to provide `fsolve` with an initial guess that's "near" your desired solution.  A good way to find such an initial guess is to just plot the expression and look for the zero crossing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# Define the expression whose roots we want to find

a = 0.5
R = 1.6

func = lambda tau : R - ((1.0 - np.exp(-tau))/(1.0 - np.exp(-a*tau))) 

# Plot it

tau = np.linspace(-0.5, 1.5, 201)

plt.plot(tau, func(tau))
plt.xlabel("tau")
plt.ylabel("expression value")
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# Use the numerical solver to find the roots

tau_initial_guess = 0.5
tau_solution = fsolve(func, tau_initial_guess)

print "The solution is tau = %f" % tau_solution
print "at which the value of the expression is %f" % func(tau_solution)
```

Answer (score 16):

You can rewrite the equation as

[image: eq]

- For integer `a` and non-zero `R` you will get `a` solutions in the complex space;
- There are analytical solutions for `a=0,1,...4`(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Roots_of_polynomials));

So in general you may have one, multiple or no solution and some or all of them may be complex values. You may easily throw [`scipy.root`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) at this equation, but no numerical method will guarantee to find all the solutions.

To solve in the complex space:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

def poly(xs, R, a):
    x = complex(*xs)
    err = R * x - x + 1 - R
    return [err.real, err.imag]

root(poly, x0=[0, 0], args=(1.2, 6))
```