# (python) solving transcendental equation

Tags: python, equation, nonlinear-optimization, transcendental-equation

i need to solve following equation:

```
0 = -1 / x**0.5) - 2 * log((alpha * x**0.5) + beta)
```

alpha and beta are given, i just need to iterate x until a certain extent.

I'm not a great python programmer, but like to implement this one. 
How might this be possible?

Best regards

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742951/solve-an-equation-using-a-python-numerical-solver-in-numpy

Comment: its not possible for me. Can someone try to get x somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The smartest to do would be to implement a solve function like Stanislav recommended. You can't just iterate over values of x until the equation reaches 0 due to Floating Point Arithmetic. You would have to .floor or .ceil your value to avoid an infinity loop. An example of this would be something like:

```
x = 0

while True:
    x += 0.1
    print(x)
    if x == 10:
        break
```

Here you'd think that x eventually reaches 10 when it adds 0.1 to 9.9, but this will continue forever. Now, I don't know if your values are integers or floats, but what I'm getting at is: Don't iterate. Use already built solve libraries.